# How to add user defined search using jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I implemented jqgrid it work fine now my problem is that I want implement jqgrid search as suppose I had one link like "Add criteria" when I click on that link it will display me popup window like jqgrid search and I set my search options in that popup for that I was used following code but it not work

```
<a href="#" id="mysearch">Add Criteria</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $("#mysearch").click(function(){
     $("#list2").jqGrid('searchGrid',{multisearch:true});
  });
```

In above code list2 is my grid id. Or is there any other jquery plguin so I can add my search criteria using that plguin?

Comment: hi replace multisearch with multipleSearch and try it..

Comment: Hi I replaced multisearch to muiltipleSearch but still it not working :(

Comment: post a fiddle if possible...so that i may help u...ru using the latest jqgrid...

Comment: Hi I used jquery.jqGrid-4.5.2 right now it not possible to me post on fiddle :(

Comment: hi k wrap the jqrid in a function and call the fucntion inside click event..

Comment: Hi wrapping jqgrid in a function and called that function on click event but new jqgrid append to old and it not display search popup.

Comment: Hi r u using a unique id for jqgrid as there are issues with jqgrid if v r not using unique id elsewhere it will append on old jqgrid as in ur case..

Comment: Hi I used unique id for both but when I doing following it work fine can u tell me is right way to call search of jqgrid my code is  $("#mysearch").click(function(){openSearch();});function openSearch(){var searchParams = {multipleSearch:true,overlay:false,closeOnEscape:true,Find:"Search",
closeAfterSearch:true,caption:"Advanced Search",searchOnEnter:true, recreateForm:true};jQuery("#list2").jqGrid('searchGrid', searchParams);}

Comment: Hi yogesh calling the grid in a function is good practice and hope ur task i accomplished and its working as expected by u...